# How to use the summation symbol to express this expression?

Tags: symbolic, summation

How to use the summation symbol to express this expression?

$$d_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{40}a_{ki}a_{kj}\qquad i\ne j,\;i,j=1,2,\dots,14$$

I don't have any simple ideas, of course I can't write them one by one. please help me.
This is what I can think of but there is no constraint i!=j and the dimension is wrong.

```
Table[Sum[Subscript[a, k, i]*Subscript[a, k, j], {k, 1, 40}], {i, 14}, {j, 14}]
```

Comment: \[{d_{i,j}} = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{40} {{a_{{\rm{k}}i}}} {a_{kj}}\quad i \ne j,i,j = 1,2,...,14\]

Comment: The picture may have failed to send, this is a latex expression

Comment: Isn't that just the expression for the $(i,j)$ entry of a product of two matrices?

Comment: 1) Do you want the $d_{ij}$ in a matrix or a list? 2) What do you want to happen when i==j? Should it be zero or some other value, or undefined? 3) What do you mean by _dimension is wrong_

Comment: This is a minimum expression for linear programming. The summation requires i!=j. I don't know how to write this expression.